# how to convert to_timestamp('12-10-18 12:00:16.565736000 PM','DD-MM-RR HH12:MI:SSXFF AM') into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one insert query in oracle ---

```
Insert into sample (name,time) values ('RJ-valley',to_timestamp('12-10-18 12:00:16.565736000 PM','DD-MM-RR HH12:MI:SSXFF AM'));

select time from sample;

output : 12-10-18 12:00:16.565736000 PM
```

same how can i insert in MySQL and i want output as same as oracle.

Comment: can you explain in detail? what will the input  and to which it should be changed?

Comment: i need  output : 12-10-18 12:00:16.565736000 PM in MySQL  But i'm getting 2012-10-18 12:00:16.565736.          I'm using DATETIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to convert `str_to_date` then do a `date_format`

so the query should be as

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@q, '%d-%m-%y %h:%i:%s.%f000 %p'),
            '%d-%m-%y %h:%i:%s.%f000 %p') AS to_date;
```

Sharing the fiddle here [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=01e1abb015a2d9568090536deeff0c29)

**p.s.**

In MySQL the maximum fraction is 6, so as you have shared 9 with last 3 are zero then no issues.